# System.Net.Http.Primitives Exception when running c# GDrive project

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client, google-drive-api

I am working on a program that uses the google drive api. When i run the program i get the exception:

> Failed to initialize Google Drive service. Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>
> at
>   Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(CreateHttpClientArgs
>   args)
>
> at
>   Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient(CreateHttpClientArgs
>   args)
>
> at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential..ctor(Initializer
>   initializer)
>
> at LibGDrive.GDrive.GetService(String userEmail)

When i check my project "LibGDrive" i could see that it references the dll System.Net.Http.Primitives whose version is 2.1.10.0 and also in the app.config i could see the same information.

```
 <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.10.0" newVersion="2.1.10.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

My Google.Api version is 1.8.1.31687 and Google.Api.Auth version is 1.8.1.31688 and i guess these are the latest available.

i think the google.Api is looking for System.Net.Http.Primitives dll of version 1.5.0.0. Not sure why. I am new to the drive api and C#. So please help as to how to proceed with this?

Comment: I have had this problem in the past, the way I've solved it is by creating a new project, then just installing the Google.Drive.Apis.Drive.v2 NuGet package from the NuGet Package Manager which seems to install everything necessary and It seems to have fixed all the problems I was getting! :) Good luck!